# Body in Nested Scroll body showing behind headerSliverBuilder

Tags: flutter, dart

I've created a flutter widget that consists of a few slivers that make up the app bar and tabs, and below that, I have the TabBarView.

1) There is an excessive amount of padding between the tabs and the body ScrollView, but I'm not sure what element is causing it.

2) When scrolling the content in the ListView, it shows behind the tab and I'm not sure what I need to do to prevent that.

3)Lastly, You can scroll until there are no more visible items in the ListView, how would you scroll similar to html/css overflow, where it stops scrolling at the end of the content?

Here's my view

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:nssa/bloc/conference/bloc.dart';

class ConferencePage extends StatelessWidget {

  final Conference conference;

  ConferencePage(@required this.conference);

  TabBar getTabBar(List<Zone> zones) {
    return  TabBar(
      tabs: zones.map((zone) {
        return new Tab(text: zone.type);
      }).toList(growable: false)
    );
  }

  TabBarView getTabBody(List<Zone> zones) {
    return TabBarView(
      children: zones.map((zone) {
        return ListView(
          children: zone.upcomingEvents().map((event) {
            return new ListTile(title: Text(event.name));
          }).toList(growable: false)
        );
      }).toList(growable: false)
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: DefaultTabController(
        length: this.conference.zones.length,
        child: NestedScrollView(
          headerSliverBuilder: (BuildContext context, bool innerBoxIsScrolled) {
            return <Widget>[
              SliverAppBar(
                expandedHeight: 200.0,
                floating: true,
                pinned: true,
                flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(
                  centerTitle: true,
                  title: Text(
                    this.conference.name,
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      fontSize: 16.0,
                    )
                  ),
                  background: Hero(
                    tag: this.conference.name,
                    child: Image.network(
                      this.conference.image,
                      fit: BoxFit.cover,
                    )
                  )
                ),
              ),
              SliverPersistentHeader(
                delegate: _SliverAppBarDelegate(
                  this.getTabBar(this.conference.zones),
                ),
                pinned: true,
              ),
            ];
          },
          body: this.getTabBody(this.conference.zones)
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        child: Icon(Icons.card_membership)
      ),
    );
  }
}

class _SliverAppBarDelegate extends SliverPersistentHeaderDelegate {
  _SliverAppBarDelegate(this._tabBar);

  final TabBar _tabBar;

  @override
  double get minExtent => _tabBar.preferredSize.height;
  @override
  double get maxExtent => _tabBar.preferredSize.height;

  @override
  Widget build(
      BuildContext context, double shrinkOffset, bool overlapsContent) {
    return new Container(
      child: _tabBar,
    );
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRebuild(_SliverAppBarDelegate oldDelegate) {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Here are my models

```
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:equatable/equatable.dart';
import 'package:meta/meta.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

import 'dart:developer';

@immutable
class Zone extends Equatable {
  final String type;
  final List<String> divisions;
  final List<Event> events;
  final DateTime _now = DateTime.now();

  Zone (
    @required this.type,
    @required this.divisions,
    @required this.events,
  );

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [type, /*divisions,*/ events];

  Event currentEvent() {
    return this.events.firstWhere((event) => event.startDate.isBefore(_now) && event.endDate.isAfter(_now), orElse: () => null);
  }

  List<Event> pastEvents() {
    return this.events.where((event) => event.endDate.isBefore(_now)).toList(growable: false);
  }

  List<Event> upcomingEvents() {
    return this.events.where((event) => event.startDate.isAfter(_now)).toList(growable: false);
  }

  factory Zone.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> zoneJSON) {
    List<String> divisions = (zoneJSON['divisions'] as List).map((division) {
      return division.toString();
    }).toList(growable: true);

    List<Event> events = (zoneJSON['events'] as List).map((event) {
      return new Event.fromJson(event);
    }).toList(growable: true);

    events.sort((a,b) => a.startDate.compareTo(b.startDate));

    return Zone(
        zoneJSON['type'],
        divisions,
        events,
    );
  }
}
@immutable
class Event extends Equatable {
  final String name;
  final String details;
  final DateTime startDate;
  final DateTime endDate;
  final String image;
  final String ticketURL;

  Event (
    @required this.name,
    @required this.details,
    @required this.startDate,
    @required this.endDate,
    @required this.image,
    @required this.ticketURL,
  );

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [name, startDate, endDate, details, image, ticketURL];

  factory Event.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> eventJSON) {
    DateFormat dateFormat = DateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    return Event(
        eventJSON['name'],
        eventJSON['details'],
        dateFormat.parse(eventJSON['startDate'].toString()),
        dateFormat.parse(eventJSON['endDate'].toString()),
        eventJSON['image'],
        eventJSON['ticketURL']
    );
  }
}
```

[image: excessive padding]

[image: content behind tab]

Comment: Have you found any solution?

Comment: is it ok if i do this UI another way ?

Comment: This question needs a good [repro]

Comment: Adding a background color to the TabBarView fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

When using a NestedScrollView, you might need to wrap your SliverAppBar with a SliverOverlapAbsorber to avoid having the body content scrolling behing the appbar.

Also, you might be better off putting your TabBar in the `bottom` of your SliverAppBar, just like in the official example.

See documentation here: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/NestedScrollView-class.html

Comment: I have a NestedScrollView that Contains a SliverAppbar Like WhatsApp, and in the Body I have Tabbars on Chat Tab there are only 4 ListTile. But my Screen is scrolling. What i want is Unless I have List Tiles more than the Viewport. It should not scroll.

Answer (score 1):

The Scaffold child must be NestedScrollView not the DefaultTabController and the child of NestedScrollView is DefaultTabController.

Use this i think so it would resolve the issuse